# Alphabetical in contact list

Tags: java, alphabetical

I have a alphabetic bar in my app contact list. I've made the alphabetical bar in XML text views A to Z, made them clickable and in java tagged them seted an ontouch listener for all of them. My problem is how do I get the index position for every letter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand you right, when the user presses the TextView for B it would give you an index of 2? If that is the case, you can just see which letter in the alphabet was clicked to get an index number since they are already sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Hi Takendarkk, can you please post a sample code? Thank you in advance